# Change price before rendering payment gatway in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cart, price, checkout-page

I need to change price of product, before rendering the payment gateway in magento2.

I have two conditions to change price for particular states  **with_in state Price** and **out of state price**.

SO, we planned to change a price **once click next button after enter the shipping address in the checkout page**.

I checked this class `Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider` get method  `getConfig`, this method to get all checkout data and proceed in checkout page. its not update after change in cart price. for following cases.

1. I try to use `checkout_cart_product_add_after` to change price, its change cart price, but its not change checkout checkout page.
2. Then, try to use **checkout session** to get quote product, then change price, that also not working me.

**Update:**

**what i did:**

I add this js file to my theme. `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/shipping.js` and update setShippingInformation function to call my ajax controller to checkout shipping address and update my price.

```
      /**
         * Set shipping information handler
         */
        setShippingInformation: function () {
            if (this.validateShippingInformation()) {
              //for change Price for functionality
               this.priceChange();
                setShippingInformationAction().done(
                    function () {
                        stepNavigator.next();
                    }
                );

            }
        },

      //Price Change Calling

      priceChange: function() {
        $.ajax({
               showLoader: true,
               url: '<base_url>/change/price',
               type: 'POST',
           complete: function(response) {
              console.log(response);
               if(response == "success"){
                 console.log("successfully change price");
               }else{
                 console.log("not change price");
               }

          },
               error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                   console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
               }
           });

      },
```

add `Price` Controller:

```
        <?php
        namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Change;

        use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

        class Price extends  \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
        {

            protected $logger;

            protected $_cart;

            protected $_eventManager;

            protected $productFactory;

            public function __construct(
                Context $context,
                \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
                \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cartModel,
                \Magento\Framework\Event\Manager $eventManager,
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
            ) {
                parent::__construct($context);
                $this->logger = $logger;
                $this->_cart = $cartModel;
                $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
                $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
            }

            public function execute()
            {
                try {

                //get Shipping Details

                    $dest_country = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId();
                    $dest_state = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getRegionCode();
                    $this->logger->addDebug($dest_country);
                    $this->logger->addDebug($dest_state);

                    $priceChange ="";
                    if($dest_country == "IN" && $dest_state == "KL"){

                    $productModel  = $this->productFactory->create();
                    $items = $this->_cart->getItems();
                    foreach($items as $item) {
                        $sku = $item->getSku();
                        $product = $productModel->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
                        $attribute_code = 'price_ik';
                        $price_ik =  $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
                        $this->logger->addDebug("Price Change Inside State");
                        $this->logger->addDebug($price_ik);
                        $beforePrice = $item->getPrice();

                        $this->logger->addDebug("Before Price Change");
                        $this->logger->addDebug($beforePrice);

                        $priceChange = $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                            'checkout_cart_product_add_after',
                            ['quote_item' => $item,  'avp_price' => $price_ik]
                        );

                        //after change price:
                        $changePrice = $item->getPrice();

                        $this->logger->addDebug("After Price Change");
                        $this->logger->addDebug($changePrice);



                        }

                        return $priceChange;

                    }else{

                    $productModel  = $this->productFactory->create();
                    $items = $this->_cart->getItems();
                    foreach($items as $item) {
                        $sku = $item->getSku();
                        $product = $productModel->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
                        $attribute_code = 'price_ok';
                        $price_ok =  $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
                        $this->logger->addDebug("Price Change Outside State");
                        $this->logger->addDebug($price_ok);
                        $priceChange = $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                            'checkout_cart_product_add_after',
                            ['quote_item' => $item,  'avp_price' => $price_ok ]
                        );

                        }

                        return $priceChange;
                    }

                } catch (\Exception $e) {


                }

            }
        }
```

add `events.xml` to  `app/code/AVP/Checkout/etc/`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
    <observer name="xxx_price_change" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomPrice" />
  </event>
</config>
```

add `CustomPrice` observer to `app\code\Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomPrice`

```
        <?php

            namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

            use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
            use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

            class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
            {
            protected $_cart;

            protected $logger;

            protected $_messageManager;

            protected $resultRedirect;

            public function __construct(
                \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
                \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cartModel,
                \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
                \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $result
            ){
                $this->_cart = $cartModel;
                $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
                $this->resultRedirect = $result;

            }
                public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {


                    $this->pricelog->info("Custom Price Event Calling");
                if($observer->getEvent()->getData('avp_price') !== ""){
                    $customPrice = $observer->getEvent()->getData('avp_price');

                    if($customPrice > 0) {
                        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
                        $item->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
                        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
                        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                        $item->save();
                        $this->_messageManager->addSuccess(__("You have changed Price based on your shipping address"));
                        echo "sucess";
                    }else {
                        $this->pricelog->info("avp price 0");
                    }
                }else{
                    $this->pricelog->info("avp price Not Found");
                }

                }

            }
```

**Update 1:**

Now, I changed quote custom price. But it's not updated in the Order summary. I need to update the product price  and order total and cart total in order summary in the checkout page.

Reference:

[image]

Suggest me, how to update order summary after change cart price.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @AnshuMishra I update my question

Comment: @Rajkumar.E is it solved i am also facing such situation can you help me